# Is every graded hereditary ring hereditary?

Tags: noncommutative-rings, projective-modules, graded-rings-modules

Let R be a graded (associative, unital) ring. If R is left graded hereditary (i.e. its left graded global dimension is 0 or 1), does it follow that R is left hereditary (i.e. its left global dimension is 0 or 1)?

Comment: The title of this good question is a good example of the ambiguity of “any” in mathematical English. I think it would be better to use “every” — I first read the title as asking if *some* graded hereditary ring is hereditary.

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda Thank you for this comment. I have changed the title.

Answer (score 7):

No, consider the graded ring $R_{\ast}=\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}]$ with $|x|=1$.  Then the functor $M\mapsto M_0$ gives an equivalence from graded $R_{\ast}$-modules to abelian groups, so $R_{\ast}$ is hereditary in the graded sense.  However, the corresponding ungraded ring is not hereditary: for example, the inhomogeneous ideal generated by $(2,x-1)$ is not a free module.